# How can I take Data from files without pandas in Python?

Tags: python, function

I have two text files as codes.txt and values.txt. Code file has categorical values and values.txt file has numerical values for the corresponding category. Continuous categories are presumed to be one segment. An example given in the figure below. Data points between 3 and 11 are all categories of “H” and this forms one segment.

I want to write a function which takes these two files (code.txt and values.txt) and return a dictionary as the output.  Dictionary should have a key for each category. After that, I need to provide a new dictionary where keys are segment id’s for each category key. I have to provide a dictionary whose keys are for each segment id. I cannot use pandas and numpy for this.

After all it should like this:

[image]

Sample Input Data (values.txt)

[image]

After getting together, they will look like:

[image]

- 1
- 0.55147

H   0.76923

H   0.131979

H   0.503175

T   0.867538

T   0.123256

Comment: kindly provide sample files to make the question more clear.

Comment: Please replace the images with examples in *text*; as it’s very difficult to copy/paste example data from an image.  Thank you.

Comment: As StackOverflow isn’t a code-writng service, please edit into your question the code of your attempt to solve this, and show what output it produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**code.txt**

```
A
A
B
B
C
C
B
C
A
C
B
A
B
A
A
C
```

**values.txt**

```
1.00
2.89
3.46
3.5443
343.234
3535.35235
253415.3512
561.343
0.544534
222.453
213.5525
4532.3435
3541.134
55.31314
341.3143
131.4534
```

**Complete code**

```
codes=[]
values=[]
with open(r"values.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        values.append(float(line.replace("\n","")))
        
with open(r"code.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        codes.append(line.replace("\n",""))
# print(codes)
# print(values)
dictt={}
for i in set(codes):
    dictt[i]={"values":[],"mean":"","length":""}
for i in range(len(codes)):
    dictt[codes[i]]["values"].append(values[i])
for key,value in dictt.items():
    dictt[key]["length"]=len(value["values"])
    dictt[key]["mean"]=sum(value["values"])/len(value["values"])

print(dictt)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It's working. However, dictionary should have a key for each category. And for each category key I need to provide a new dictionary where keys are segment id’s. 

It's working for dictt['H']. But it got an error for dictt['H'][1]

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Oops,I Just forget about the category key.

Comment: How can i add it?